# how to validate year in dateformat dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

My issue is I'm getting date data as 12-06-467346 as date,.how to validate the year.

Issue: 12-06-467346
if the year character is more than 4, I need to block this and then I need toreturn the current date

Comment: Which year is that? 467346?

Comment: its is the wrong data from API, I need to detect this year format

Comment: @Akif question edited

Comment: What have you tried?  Why not just use `DateFormat` to parse the year as usual and then check if the year is > 9999?

Comment: will check this

Comment: Does date string have a specific format?